# how get the value of second child element in xml using XElement in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I want to get the value of the second price element.we cant get last or first directly.but I don't have an idea how to get the second element directly.
this is the xml....( I put only the needed part.my xml is valid)

```
<Departure>
    <Date>2016-09-24T00:00:00.0000000</Date>
    <Pricing>
      <Price>
        <Type>ADT</Type>
        <Value>299.00</Value>
        <Qty>20</Qty>
      </Price>
      <Price>
        <Type>CHD</Type>
        <Value>230.00</Value>
        <Qty>5</Qty>
      </Price>
      <Price>
        <Type>INF</Type>
        <Value>150.00</Value>
        <Qty>5</Qty>
      </Price>
      <Price>
        <Type>FAM</Type>
        <Value>0.00</Value>
        <Qty>0</Qty>
      </Price>
      <Price>
        <Type>SEN</Type>
        <Value>299.00</Value>
        <Qty>20</Qty>
      </Price>
    </Pricing>
  </Departure>
  <Departure>
```

this is how I took the Last()

```
 numberofDays = itm.Elements("Itinerary").Elements("ItineraryItem").Elements("EndDay").Last().Value,
```

like this I want to get the value of the second price element.(which the Type valud is "CHD")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an element at position `N` you could skip `N-1` elements, and take `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var secondPrice = item.GetElements("Price").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most up-to-date way to work with XML, but this'll work

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(XML);

    XmlNode secondPrice = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Price")[1];
```